# Scrapy-redis can not connect to server in Docker

Tags: docker, redis, scrapy

I run my redis as a docker containner

```
docker run  --name redis_env --hostname redis \
            -p 6379:6379 \
            -v $PWD/DBVOL/redis/data:/data:rw \
            --privileged=true \
            -d redis redis-server
```

I can connect my redis server through Redis Desktop Manager

[image]

But when scrapy-redis want to connect server, it refused with error code `111`. Here is my setting.py:

```
# Set up Redis Server
REDIS_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'

# Enable scheduler stores requested queues
SCHEDULER = 'scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler'

# Ensure all scraper share same duplicates filter through redis
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter'

# Don't cleanup redis queues
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   #'GeoCrawler.pipelines.GeocrawlerPipeline': 300,
    'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300
}
```

Here is debug message:

[image]

What wrong with it ?

By the way I can connect successfully with python console:

```
>>>import redis
>>>redis.Connection("redis://localhost:6379/0")
Connection<host=redis://localhost:6379/0,port=6379,db=0>
```

Comment: Probably the issue of the host. Please try with docker container ip to connect the redis. Command:
`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`

Comment: @PS1212，Thanks a lots! It works well when I change the container ip.But could you tell me the reason? Why I use 127.0.0.1 as the host ip in Redis Desktop Manager,It still work.